# kendoTreeView post only leafs

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I new to KendoUI and I would like some help. 
I have a Tree View with check boxes. How to post (on submit form) only checked leafs of the tree?

See example:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: true,
            dataSource: localDataSource,
            dataTextField: ["text"],
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true,
                template: "<input type='checkbox' name='checkedFiles[#= item.id #]' value='true' />"

            },
        });
```

EDIT: I have found one way
template: "# if(!item.hasChildren){# #} else {# #}#"

Comment: What do you mean by "*post (on submit form) only checked leafs*"? Are you trying to just get all the leaf nodes with check? Please include the code of your "post" event.